# Check image HTTP status codes using jQuery/JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, http-headers

is it possible to check the status codes of images using jQuery/JS?

For example,

```
img1 = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/26/YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg/260px-YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg";

if(statusCheck(img1) == 404){
    /do something
}elseif(statusCheck(img1) == 403){
    //do something else
}elseif(statusCheck(img1) == 304){
    //do something else
}
```

Thanks

Comment: WHEN and HOW you're going to download such image?

Comment: You could try accomplish that with XMLHTTPRequest but you have to be aware that most of the sites don't allow crossDomain requests (and for good reasons!)

Answer (score 6):

You can construct an `Image` object, which isn't affected by cross-origin restrictions:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/26/YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg/260px-YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg"

image.onload = function() {
    alert('Image has loaded');
};

image.onerror = function() {
    alert('Image did not load');
};
```

Image loading is asynchronous, so making a function that returns the error code won't be a good idea.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/apyL7/**

Also, there doesn't seem to be a way to get the response code, so you're limited to knowing only whether the image loaded or not.

Comment: Thanks, So you are saying it is not possible to retrieve the http status codes? For example 304 is different than 200 even though they can both load.

Comment: What about Flickr images that have been removed, hidden and moved? Flickr doesn't remove them physically, but notifies with 301, that the image has been moved permanently. Try this one: http://farm9.static.flickr.com/8521/8619601616_b4ba28c3b0_z.jpg (it's broken, but still loaded and 'load' event is fired).