# How to monitor an image source for fully loaded status

Tags: javascript, image, get, xmlhttprequest, onload

I am loading a large number of images into a dynamic DIV and I am using a preloader to get the images.

```
imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = imgpath + imgname;
```

Each of these events creates a GET that I can see and monitor in Firebug.

If I know the name and path of an image, can I watch the relevant XMLHttpRequest to see if the GET has completed?

I do not want to rely on (or use) .onload events for this process.

The pseudo would look something like this...

```
if (imageObj.GET = 'complete')
```

Has anyone had any experience of this?

**EDIT 1**

Thanks to the help from Bart (see below) I have changed my image preloader to store an array of the image objects...

```
function imagePreLoader(imgname) {
    images[imgnum] = new Image();
    images[imgnum].src = imgpath + imgname;// load the image
    imgnum ++;
}
```

And then, after all my other functions have run to build the content DIVs, I used the image.complete attribute in the following...

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    imgcount = imgnum - 1; // because the imgnum counter ++ after src is called.
    ok = 1;

    for (i=0; i<imgcount; i++) {
        if (images[i].complete == false){
            ok = 0;
        }
    }

    if (ok == 1) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        showIndexOnLoad();
    }
}, 1000);
```

This waits until all the images are complete and only triggers the `showIndexOnLoad()` function when I get the 'ok' from the interval function.

All images now appear as I wanted, all at once with no additional waits for the GETs to catch up.

Well done Bart for putting me on to the [image.complete](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_complete.asp) attribute.

Comment: what do you mean by "watch the relevant XMLHttpRequest"? you try to catch image's load event?

Comment: The .onload event fires before the GET is complete. I want to monitor the status of the generated GET only. The GET items are visible in Firebug, I need to access that information in JS.

Comment: Just wrote a simple [jquery.preload](https://github.com/onedott/jquery-preload) plugin to take advantage of the `image.complete` property. Hope it can be useful to you.

Comment: Nice code Bart, but over here I am a .js lib free zone! Thanks for your help though. It would be a good idea to add the code to your answer...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can watch the `complete` property of the image to see if the image is fully loaded or not.

Here's an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/t3esV/1/

```
function load (source) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = source;

    console.log('Loading ' + source);

    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (img.complete) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            complete(img);
        }
    }, 400);
};

function complete(img) {
    console.log('Loaded', img.src);
    document.body.appendChild(img);
};
```

*Note: This example fails to clear the interval when something goes wrong and `complete` is never set to `true`.*

### Update

I wrote a simple [jQuery.preload plugin](https://github.com/onedott/jquery-preload) to take advantage of the `image.complete` property.

Comment: The .onload function fires before the GET finishes. The Firebug log clearly shows that the GETs complete after 11 seconds but the .onload fires after 5 seconds. I do not want to use .onload. Please see the text of the question.

Comment: because the images fire their .onload events before they are fully loaded and ready to display. Especially if you are adding them dynamically as an html string to a DIV.innerHTML.

Comment: I see your point. Updated my answer to a more suitable solution.

Comment: Thanks Bart. am having a look at the img.complete property. Have you had any luck with a img.complete = function() approach?

Comment: This will not detect if an image did not load though. Only that it finished trying to load. This looks like it might be a better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14226702/148390

Comment: @Dex the question is about detecting if the image is loaded. onload() will not be triggered for cached images. That is why my answer makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting problem, and I am afraid there is no actual solution to this. The `load` event for images is when the image is being rendered and the browser knows the width and height of it.

What you would be after would be a tag-applicable `readystatechange` event. Alas, only IE allows you to bind those to non-document elements, so this is not an option.

There are a bunch of plug-ins that allow you to go around it, as well. One pretty hot one is https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded , which has the added advantage of dealing with all the browser differences very efficiently. It, however, still relies on the `load` event (and I am pretty sure this is the only way to start doing what you want to do).

Comment: Problem solved without plug-ins. Well done to Bart for putting me onto the image.complete attribute.