# Javascript reloading preloaded image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, preload

The following piece of Javascript is intended to preload an image, set a div's background to the image and then fade the whole div in...

```
$("<img/>")
    .attr("src", "../services/imageResize.php?img=" + img + "&width=150")
    .load(function(e){
        $("<div/>", {
            class: "smallThumb"
        })
        .css("background", "url(" + $(this).attr("src") + ") no-repeat center center")
        .appendTo(images)
        .fadeIn(500);

        if(count == imgTotal)
        {
            loadingImages = false;
            images.css("background","#fff");
        }
    });
count++;
```

I've tested it in Chrome and Safari; both fade the div in and then finish loading the image. I'm perplexed as to what is causing it to reload the image for the .css statement.

Comment: check the headers on the requests for both images and see if appropriate cache logic is being output. perhaps you've got no-cache headers in play, so the browser is forced to get both versions, even though they're the same image.

Comment: There are two parts, caching good, not loading the DOM src with a big image and letting CSS do the work the other.  caching just hides the coding issue.

Comment: As Marc B said, since you're getting your image from a PHP script, headers can be set to no cache by your web server. If you wish, post a link to one of those images so we can check.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried hardcoding the image into the page hidden and seeing what happens? Part of the issue is that you are passing URL params which could be making the images unique to each other.

Answer (score 0):

The are two different things.  HTML DOM and CSS, it will load it twice.  They both don't really know about each other.  Just because you use the same src "string" does not mean they use the same src image content.  I would test it out with the image src set to a single pixel type of thing and then load the background.  This is a well documented approach to CSS backgrounding images.  Also caching can help it at least not request it twice from the server.  A good thing to do anyhow.

Comment: OH and stop using the img take for the css background stuff.  The img part is really pointless looking at your code, css is setting the background for the div.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the `onload` event fires before the image is fully loaded. *If you're assuming the image is fully loaded it will appear like it's reloading.*

The `img.onload` will trigger whenever the bowser is ready to render the image. It is no garantie that the image will be fully loaded. The only way to test if an image is fully loaded is with the `img.complete` attribute.

Some time ago I answered to the question [How to monitor an image source for fully loaded status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648546/how-to-monitor-an-image-source-for-fully-loaded-status/16649718#16649718)

After the answer I wrote a little [jQuery plugin which utilizes the `complete` attribute](https://github.com/onedott/jquery-preload).

You could use it like e.g.

```
$(function () {
    $.preload('your-image.png').progress(function (img) {
        // set background
        $('body').css('background', 'url(' + img.src + ')');
    });
});
```