# Img.onload not firing when dynamically setting src to dataURI

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, html5-canvas

I am having trouble getting the onLoad handler to fire when the src of imgGraph is loaded with a generated dataURI. The dataURI is generated from a d3.js visualization (svg) using canvas.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById(visual + '-canvas');
if(visual == "graph"){
     console.log('graph logic n stuff')
     canvas.width = 558;
     canvas.height = 558;
     var graph = d3.select('#graph-svg').node();
     var svg_xml = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(graph);
     var imgGraph = new Image();
     var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
     var imageData;
     imgGraph.onload = function(){
         console.log('img loaded')
         context.drawImage(imgGraph, 0, 0);
         imageData = getImgData(canvas);
         console.log(imageData)
         def.resolve(imageData)
     }
     console.log('setting src')
     imgGraph.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,"+btoa(svg_xml);
}
```

The img src is being set, but the img.onload is never fired.
When logging and surfing to the datauri, the image is being displayed however.
Other images seem to fire the onload event correctly.

[DataURI - PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/yV3VyvGy)

Comment: try `onerror` - because there is an error

Comment: the error is with the `è` in `Olivier Frère`

Comment: and the Adrien `é` in `Adrien Ampélas`

Comment: @JaromandaX I've tried onerror, and that indeed does trigger, but it doesn't give any info about what went wrong.

Comment: well ... try putting the data uri in your pastebin into the address bar - firefox will tell you what it doesn't like about it

Comment: though, I see that chrome will load it no problems - cross browser code is a nightmare, isn't it

Comment: @JaromandaX ohh, Chrome doesn't seem to have any problems with it. So the dataURI is incorrect? The onload still doesn't work on chrome eventhough it parses the dataURI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't base64 encode your svg.
Instead one should prefer an percent encoded version, or for huge svg, a blobURI :

```
img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(yourSVGMarkup);
```

or

```
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(
  new Blob([yourSVGMarkup], {
    type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf8'
    })
  );
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwytj41q/) to demonstrate the difference.

But you should note that SVGs loaded inside an `<img>` element can't load any external resources. So you'll have to base64 encode all the images linked in your svg prior to extract the markup if you want to draw them on your canvas too.
When this will be done, your svg markup will indeed be long, and maybe too long for a dataURI version.

That's when the blobURI is useful.

*PS: if you need help for appending your raster images inside your svg, check [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34042910/convert-svg-to-png-with-applied-images-as-background-to-svg-elements/34043188#34043188)*

Comment: Thanks, this worked! The implementation with blob even yields a better quality than my previous method!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

imgGraph.complete = function(){

Comment: Doesn't this only work on img-tags that are appended to the DOM? If I try this I get the following error: _Cannot assign to read only property 'complete' of object '#<HTMLImageElement>_

Comment: Yes, it does, and I am not sure why this does not have the same result. For an image created in the way you describe you might want to create a loop check for non-zero width / height for the image object.

Or loop to see if the imgGraph.complete property is true.

Comment: See my previous Q&A:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648546/how-to-monitor-an-image-source-for-fully-loaded-status